# Frame thickness in Framed[]

Tags: output-formatting

I need to change the frame thickness in `Framed[]` in order to create a legend box. How can I set the frame thickness in `Framed[]`?

`Framed[1/x + y, FrameStyle->Thick]` does not work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right, it doesn't work, but you can use this alternative:

```
Grid[{{"The Thick Red Frame"}}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness@10]]
```

[image]